# as3/Flex: if SWF is bigger than screen, FlashDebugger cuts off the content. Firefox doesn't. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, debugging, flex4

I'm displaying a 720x1280 image in a 720x1280 SWF. My screen is 1366x768.

The visualization is awful since my image is cut off (although internally the image's size is still 720x1280 when I do trace() ).

Everything is suitably displayed on Firefox.

Why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't the right solution, but it could be helpful for anyone else:

My init() function checks if the screen resolution is large enough to display my application properly:

```
private function init():void
{
if(Capabilities.screenResolutionX<=1023 || Capabilities.screenResolutionY<=767)
  {
  Alert.show("In order to view this application properly, " +
  "please adjust your screen resolution to 1024 x 768 or greater.", "Atention");
  }
}
```

I hope you find it useful.

*Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the HTM embedding your SWF is set to use 100% of the browser window width and height